# how model work with controller in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I created this code in a  controller but it does not work.
My view is register member with username and password. I want to add it on mysql by model not query builder.
I am using laravel framework

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\myModel;
// use DB;

class myController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function register()
    {
        return view('register');
    }
    public function getRegister(Request $request)
    {
        $username = $request->username;
        $password = md5($request->password);

        $mem           = new App\myModel;
        $mem->username = $username;
        $mem->password = $password;
        $mem->save();
        echo 'done!';
    }
}
```

Comment: Made the code more clear + changed what I understood, more edits might be required

Comment: I am newbie. you should know newbie can't do it, just take step by step from begin to advance to understand everything so that I can make it more clear for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put `use App\myModel;` at the top, you only have to do `$mem = new myModel;` in your code.

But I would advice against registering users in this way. Laravel has a great package to handle anything related to logins, registrations, etc: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication